# How to extract time cost from Postsql explain in python

Tags: python, postgresql

I output the content from `explain` command of postgres for my sql query into a .txt file.
Here is the first line I got from `explain` command of postgres

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on r  (cost=3656.95..15795.10 rows=6094 width=39)
```

I am trying to write a python script to extract the time cost for getting all rows (`15795.10`) in Python.

```
with open(output_file, 'r') as output:
    for line in output.readlines():
        # extract time cost here
```

Any idea on how to extract this information while I read the .txt line by line? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For machine-readable output the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/using-explain.html) recommends using a different EXPLAIN format.

```
EXPLAIN (FORMAT JSON) SELECT * FROM foo;
```

would give you a structured approach by using the [python json library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) for example.

Otherwise you would have to use pattern matching via regular expressions in python.

There is also 'jq' for interpreting JSON on the command-line if you don't need python for something else.

Comment: Woah! Now that's neat! :D